# Is anyone been able to use the Chase Banking Website using Ubuntu?

Tags: browser, compatibility

In the past I was able to log onto the Chase banking website.

Time went by and I found they would redirect my browsers (Chrome, Firefox, etc.) to the mobile site when I tried to log on.

When that happened I went searching for an answer and I was able to find a post somewhere that explained there was a work-around where you could log onto the rewards site for for Chase and then switch back to the main site and it would not redirect you to the mobile site when you did that.

Time went by and the work-around worked for months until about last week. Now when I try to log onto the rewards site I get redirected to the mobile site.

I contacted Chase and they said they were sorry about this but did not offer any advice other than to use Windoze instead of Linux.

I'm asking here in case someone has a way to go on using Chase.

Thanks,
MC

Comment: Is this using Firefox or Chromium? Did you try both?

Comment: And `etc` refers to which browsers exactly?

Comment: Some browsers allow you to use a different user agent string. Maybe that would help?

Comment: I use Chase without issue. https://www.chase.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try suing Chase?  There might be a way to do that.  You could ask on leagal stack exchange.

Comment: That's totally what Chase The Linux-Hating Bank needs.